# Limiting write rate of a device

Tags: devices, storage

How does one go about limiting the write/read rate of a device, E.G., USB drive, SD card?

Motivation behind this question is covered [here (superuser.com)](https://superuser.com/questions/453398/).

Comment: [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)

Comment: It's a bit difficult, and I don't see how it would be useful. If your data can go through a pipe, pipe through [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml). The slower step will naturally limit the rate of the transfer. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Gilles experimentation, I'm thinking of an application which can't pipe data.